# regarding CFLAGS setting in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, compilation, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, gcc-warning

While compiling Linux kernel I got following error :

```
no previous prototype for 'foo' [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
```

Command used to compile kernel:

```
 make -C kernel ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
```

I tried following command but not working

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- CFLAGS=-Wno-error
```

So I want to know to how to set CFLAGS to -Wno-error in Linux kernel from directory make command.

I know its great to have -Werror set and fix problem instead but as of now I want to know how to set CFLAGS to -Wno-error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you mean `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-`, not `CROSS_COMPILE=arm=eabi-` (note the `=` between `arm` and `eabi`).

Comment: @LucaCeresoli thanks updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use **ccflags-module_name**, or **ccflags-y** to set it globally:

```
ccflags-foo.o := -Wno-error
```

or

```
ccflags-y := -Wno-error
```

As an alternative, you can use **KBUILD_CFLAGS** environment variable.

But I would fix your mistake instead of shutting up compiler.

Comment: thanks but how to set them in environment or give from make command line ?

Comment: this does not answer the question of how to set this from the command line.
I assume you need to pass to make
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- ccflags-y=-Wno-error